# different versions of python missing pymssql

Tags: python, pymssql

I have python2.7.3 in /usr/bin/

this version can import pymssql without error

i have python2.7.11 in /usr/local/bin/

this version gets an error when importing pymssql

```
    $ sudo pip install pymssql
    Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pymssql in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
    Cleaning up...

    $ python
    Python 2.7.11 (default, Feb  9 2016, 14:42:25)
    [GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    />>> import pymssql
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named pymssql

    $ which python
    /usr/local/bin/python
```

how can i install pymssql to the version of python2.7.11?

Comment: If you need both versions and you need specific modules for specific versions you may wish to read up on [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)

Answer (score 0):

When you run `sudo pip` you are invoking `/usr/bin/python`.  Install your package without `sudo`.  I agree with @Michael Frystacky--using virtualenv will save you from using `sudo pip` ever again.